# Can't access my computer from port 443

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, webserver, ufw

I run a webserver off port 443 in Ubuntu 20.04 server. About 20 minutes ago, it just stopped working all by itself, **I haven't touched the computer in days, and no one else has either**. It was working fine an hour ago.

I can still access the PC via SSH, and ping it (locally).

[image]

Any ideas on what I should do to troubleshoot? I've rebooted multiple times, it hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

My ISP decided to reassign me a new 'static' ip. I'm gonna have fun changing literally everything!

Comment: If you paid extra for a static IP, a refund may be in order ;)

Comment: @thomasrutter ikr! I'm looking into it right now